# How can I translate a keyboard press to a value in my Java program?

Tags: java

In a text adventure game written in Java, I want the character race to be as follows( the number corresponds to the key the user types):

```
   // Character Race
    
    // 1) Human
    // 2) Dwarf
    // 3) Elf
    // 4) Orc
```

How do I write that out to the player?

Like this?
So I ask the user which race they want:

```
    System.out.print("Enter character race: ");
    charRace = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Your character's race is " + charRace);
```

How do I tell my program that 1 = Human, 2 = Dwarf, etc...??

Do I need to create a dictionary or something similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a little out of the range of scope, but for me, when you have a limited range of possible values, I'd tend to look towards using a `enum`

```
enum Race {
    HUMAN(1), DWARF(2), ELF(3), ORC(4);
    
    private int value;

    private Race(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    
    public static Race from(int value) {
        for (Race race : Race.values()) {
            if (race.getValue() == value) {
                return race;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    
}
```

Then you can do fun things like...

```
Race race = Race.from(1);
if (race == null) {
    System.out.println("Invalid selection");
} else {
    switch (race) {
        case DWARF:
            System.out.println("Gunghrim Dwarf!");
            break;
        case ELF:
            System.out.println("Welcome Elf!");
            break;
        case HUMAN:
            System.out.println("Welcome Human!");
            break;
        case ORC:
            System.out.println("Welcome Orc!");
            break;
    }
}
```

You could even automate the menu.  Start by adding something like...

```
public String getProperName() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(32);
    String name = name();
    sb.append(name.charAt(0));
    sb.append(name.substring(1).toLowerCase());
    return sb.toString();
}
```

to the `Race` enum and then you could create a menu doing something like...

```
List<Race> races = Arrays.asList(Race.values());
races.sort(new Comparator<Race>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Race o1, Race o2) {
        return o1.getValue() - o2.getValue();
    }
});
for (Race race : races) {
    System.out.println(race.getValue() + ") " + race.getProperName());
}
```

which prints

```
1) Human
2) Dwarf
3) Elf
4) Orc
```

Have a look at the [enums type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) trail for more details

Answer (score 2):

You could just use some if statements to identify the entered race. Something like this

```
if(charRace == 1){
            String race = "Human";
        } else if(charRace == 2){
            String race = "Dwarf";
        } else if(charRace == 3){
            String race = "Elf";
        } else{
            String race = "Orc";
        }
```

Maybe not the most efficient way to do this though.

Comment: And then I would just print that out every time I needed to show that on the screen?

Comment: Yeah that would work.

Comment: I would recommend a switch case in this scenario.

Comment: This if else is not ideal since if I write "hello" it would still be the same as if I wrote "Orc".

Comment: @TheBlindHawk - It depends.  The problem with using `switch` is that you will end up **hard wiring** the races into the code all over the place.  Makes it harder to add new ones.  (But I agree that `switch` would probably be better than an `if` ... `else if` ... chain.)

Comment: Yes, I agree that a switch case wouldn't be ideal either, but still better than an if-else.

Comment: If else is fine. If you're worried about invalid input just change the else clause to an else if for the case Orc is entered and then a final else clause which prints the user did not enter a valid input.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just using integers wouldn't a simple Array be the better choice?

```
String races[] = {"Dwarf","Elf","Human","Orc"};
System.out.println("You selected: "+races[charRace]);
```

edit:
If you want error handling:

```
String races[] = {"Dwarf","Elf","Human","Orc"};
if(charRace>=0&&charRace<races.length)
    System.out.println("You selected: "+races[charRace]);
else
    System.out.println("Error: invalid input!");
```

Also it is definetely more efficient to use a switch case over an if-else!
Here is an example, althought I dont recommend it since you are handling integers!!

```
    switch (charRace) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("You selected Dwarf");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("You selected Elf");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("You selected Human");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("You selected Orc");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Error: invalid input!");
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want this program more sustainable, you should use inherithence.

Like:

```
public class Orc extends Race{
}

public class Human extends Race{
}
```

After creation of the all races, you can create a method for creating new race for given number.
For example:

```
public static Race createRace(int raceType){
  if(raceType == 1)
    return new Orc();
  else if(raceType == 2)
    return new Human();
}
```

Also, you can define different variables and different methods for your races.